# Direction VS Service VS Département

Tags: sens

Quelles sont les différences entre la Direction, le Service et le Département ? Quelle est de la plus grande taille et de la plus petite taille ?

Eg :
Dir. Financier —— Le service de la comptabilité —— Le comptable
Dir. Commercial —— Service Commercial —— Commercial
Le service de la production
Le service des achats
Le service des ventes

Merci infiniment !

Comment: Que donne une recherche dans un dictionnaire ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Direction** provient de **diriger**, elle peut signifier, entre autre, la place où les décisions sont prises: l'administration (le(s) directeur(s) et le corps administratif). Elle peut signifier aussi orientation, sens, voie.

**Service** est un produit (matériel ou non) offert par quelqu'un ou pour quelqu'un: service de dépannage, service de réparation, service financier.

**Département** signifie dans le contexte de la question la place où s'effectue un travail ou un service et dans ce cas les deux termes *département* et *service* peuvent se substituer.

Je n'ai pas compris la question sur la taille, mais *le département* a *une direction* qui prend des décisions et ce département offre *des services*.

Je ne crois pas que la question de taille s'applique ici, un département est un endroit physique, la direction ce sont des gens, le service est un produit qui peut être tangible ou pas.

Comment: En entreprise, on peut utiliser "département" par métonymie comme synonyme de "service", au sens de "division interne". Ex: certains entreprises parlent de *service informatique*, d'autres de *département informatique*, sans qu'il n'y ait une véritable différence.

Comment: Les exemples donnés dans la question avec "service" correspondent d'ailleurs tous à ce que décrit Greg dans son commentaire...

Answer (score -2):

Voici quelques précisions dans le domaine du gouvernement. Le domaine commercial et administratif privé est laissé à d'autres réponses.

> « Sous l'Ancien Régime, chacun des secrétaires d'État dirigeait une forme de département en fonction de ses attributions.» ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minist%C3%A8re_fran%C3%A7ais#Historique)).

De nos jours le département n'est plus qu'une division territoriale administrative de la France; le pays est divisé en 101 départements.

[image]

(Dans ce qui suit, mise en caractères gras due à user LPH)

From *[Wikepédia, Cabinet ministériel](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabinet_minist%C3%A9riel)*

> Chaque membre d'un gouvernement [ministre] dispose de collaborateurs directs qui l'assistent dans sa tâche de direction des **services** dont il a la charge. Ces collaborateurs sont regroupés au sein d'un organisme que l'on appelle le **cabinet ministériel**.

> Chaque ministre ou secrétaire d’état est aidé dans ses fonctions par son cabinet qui regroupe soit des proches politiques qui travaillent depuis longtemps avec le ministre (anciens attachés parlementaires, militants, collaborateurs dans une mairie), soit des hauts fonctionnaires recrutés dans l’administration, et qui ont choisi de se marquer politiquement.

Dans l'administration centrale française les directions et les services sont les grandes divisions des ministères.

From [Wikipédia, ministère](https://www.vie-publique.fr/fiches/20224-quest-ce-quun-ministere)

> Les services d'un ministère sont répartis entre une **administration centrale**, le plus souvent localisée à Paris, et des **services** déconcentrés en région.

From *[Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minist%C3%A8re_fran%C3%A7ais#Services_d%C3%A9concentr%C3%A9s)*

L'organisation des services centraux de chaque ministère en **directions générales**, **directions** et **services** est fixée par décret, leur organisation en **sous-directions** est fixée par un arrêté du ministre concerné

La hiérarchie administrative place les directions au dessus des services ([réf.](https://www.vie-publique.fr/fiches/20229-comment-sorganise-ladministration-centrale))

> Les **directions** (parfois **directions générales**) : elles peuvent être thématiques et correspondre alors à un domaine d’activité du ministère, comme la **direction de l’eau et de la biodiversité** au ministère de la transition écologique et solidaire, ou fonctionnelles et alors transversales, comme les **directions en charge des ressources humaines**. […]
> Chaque **direction** comporte des **subdivisions** dont l’appellation varie selon les ministères. Il peut s’agir de **sous-directions**, de **services** ou encore de **divisions**. À leur tête, les **sous-directeurs**, les **chefs de service** ou **[chefs] de division** sont nommés en vertu de règles statutaires.
> L’unité de base au sein des différents ministères est le **bureau** dirigé par un chef de bureau.